# One Selection Field Depends on Another In Openerp 7 with syntax and example

Tags: field, selection, openerp-7

We have created 4 Selection field but all these fields are dependent on another. Once I select the first field then on time next selection fields content should be changed as well.

please, can anyone help me to get sort out this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use on-change function on the selection fields. Please provide the code to get more explanation.